# prototype js: rotating div display using $$ for dynamic divs

Tags: prototypejs, banner, rotation

I'm wondering why the following code doesn't work, where "banner" is the css class of each of four different divs. The resulting page displays all images for one second, and then they all vanish.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var bannerArray = new Array();
    bannerArray = $$(".banner");

    bannerArray.each(function (b) {
        b.hide();
    });
    bannerArray.each(function (b) {
        b.show();
        Element.hide.delay(1, b.id);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`delay` doesn't delay *all* code execution. It only delays the invocation of a specific function; the rest of your code gets executed right away, while the delay is counting down in the background. So you're setting a "hide timer" for each element at the same time. Since they all have the same 1-second delay, they all fire 1 second after being set.

Try this instead

```
(function() { // wrap everything in a function to avoid polluting the global namespace
    var banners = $$('.banner'); // no need to create an empty array first
    banners.invoke('hide');      // no need to use each

    function showNextBanner() {
        banners.last().hide();         // hide previous banner
        banners.first().show();        // show next banner
        banners.push(banners.shift()); // first element moves to become last element
        showNextBanner.delay(1);       // set a timeout to show the next banner
    }

    showNextBanner(); // start the banner rotation/looping
}());
```

[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PrsDd/)

Comment: @dcoli: heh, I hope the things you learned were useful, then :) -- By the way, if my answer worked, please click the checkmark next to it

Comment: To replace show() with scriptaculous's appear(), can I just switch them? Not finding the function for some reason.

Comment: @dcoli: yes, you should be able to just use "appear()" if you've got scriptaculous included. However, it'll look a little weird since one banner will just hide immediately, while the other fades in. So better to fade out one element, and fade in the other. Also, you'll wan't to use some absolute/fixed positioning so they don't stack vertically. [Here's a demo that seems to be working] (http://jsfiddle.net/PrsDd/3/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, turns out I was using the <script /> ending to the script tag instead of <script></script>, so scriptaculous wasn't loading. Go figure.

Comment: I'm having another difficulty with this, and I _think_ its due to an event firing in the middle of the rotation loop, which forks the thread and calls the same actions more often than intended. If you are interested you can see the new problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342911/javascript-bad-algorithm-firing-multiple-threads).